# EACCESS open/users/myusername/.plugman/plugman.log in ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using mac and try to run this command

```
ionic start myproject blank
```

I got an error

```
EACCESS open/users/myusername/.plugman/plugman/log
```

when I visit myusername folder I didn't see plugman folder too.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the ionic cli?

Comment: i am using terminal of mac. run this command 

ionic start myproject blank

Comment: run `sudo npm install -g ionic` to make sure you have the latest version of ionic installed and try again pls.

Comment: now got this error  getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com